# I need to keep user authenticated when switching from one app to another in flutter. Like facebook and messenger

Tags: authentication, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have two apps that have common users and can go from one app to another. I need to save data like password and email or authentication data like token cookies so that I can access it from the other application. Is it possible and safe?
I think of it as facebook and messenger when it passes for the first time from facebook to messenger "Continue as...". Both applications are in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin thouth it is [Account manager](https://pub.dev/packages/account_manager_plugin)

Or you can implement it yourself by a native way then use `MethodChannel` to query iformations from device.

1. For Android you can use [AccountMany](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth)

Note there is a warnig about this package because user informations passed  here are not encrypted. Therefor you should encrypt them before storing into device

> Remember: When it comes to security code, follow the "Mythbusters" rule: don't try this at home! Consult a security professional before implementing any custom account code.

2. For Ios read [this](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/adding-a-settings-bundle-to-an-iphone-app/)  and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html)